# Convert Jackson to Play Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, jackson

I am trying to convert class with Jackson annotations to Play's JsObject. As I know, it should be done by converting it to JsonNode and then to JsValue/JsObject.

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val jsNode: JsonNode = mapper.valueToTree(status)
val jsValue: JsObject = mapper.treeToValue(jsNode, classOf[JsObject])
```

but got exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "anticipatedClosing" (class play.api.libs.json.JsObject), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "fields", "value"])
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: play.api.libs.json.JsObject["anticipatedClosing"])
...
```

What was done wrong?
Currently I am converting Jackson -> String -> Play Json, but it looks ugly

Comment: Would you include the class you want to convert, please?

Answer (score 1):

add PlayJsonModule to your objectMapper

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(PlayJsonModule)
val jsValue: JsObject = mapper.treeToValue(jsNode, classOf[JsObject])
```